# John the Ripper missing formats

Tags: hash, password-cracking

I have an sha256 hash that I am trying to crack with John the Ripper. However, it doesn't recognize raw-sha256, raw-md5, or any hash format other than descrypt, bsdicrypt, md5crypt, bcrypt, LM, AFS, tripcode,dummy, crypt.

Can anyone tell me either how to fix my john or add the missing hash formats?

Comment: How to fix my 'john'? Made my day. ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think you'd get a better answer/response from the [John the Ripper Community](http://www.openwall.com/community/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

John 1.7.9 with Jumbo patch 6 has you covered. From: http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2012/06/29/1

```
New hashes:
* IBM RACF [OpenMP]  (Dhiru)
  - thanks to Nigel Pentland (author of CRACF) and Main Framed for providing
  algorithm details, sample code, sample RACF binary database, test vectors
* sha512crypt (SHA-crypt) [OpenMP, CUDA, OpenCL]  (magnum, Lukas, Claudio)
  - previously supported in 1.7.6+ only via "generic crypt(3)" interface
* sha256crypt (SHA-crypt) [OpenMP, CUDA]  (magnum, Lukas)
  - previously supported in 1.7.6+ only via "generic crypt(3)" interface
```

Comment: Thanks! I had actually gotten jtr through homebrew. So I actually just had to run 

    `brew uninstall john`
    `brew install john-jumbo`

and now it's working perfectly!